# Git: deploying to a web site from two repositories

Tags: git

I would like to use git to upload files to my web site. However, the site is developed using two different git repositories. Each repository contains the files for a different part of the site.

Here's the part that is working:

I have a web site at example.com. On this remote server, I have set up a folder at `/var/www/example/web/` from which the site is served. I have also created a folder at `/var/www/example/git/web.git/`, and initialized this as a bare git repository. The `hooks/post-receive` file in this folder is an executable text file with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/example/web git checkout -f
```

On my development machine, I have a local git repository with a remote branch called `dotcom`:

```
git remote -v
dotcom  ssh://user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/var/www/example/git/web.git (fetch)
dotcom  ssh://user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/var/www/example/git/web.git (push)
```

When I call `git push dotcom master`, this part of the site is updated as expected.

Here's the part I need to figure out:

I have a second repository where I am developing a new web application. I am using a development site at`'example.net` to test this. The site at `example.net` is working fine, but some parts of the application are ready for deployment to `example.com`. I do not want to deploy everything to `example.com`: just the parts that are ready.

Here's what I have tried:

In the second repository, I created an orphan branch:

```
git checkout --orphan fordotcom
```

I unstaged all parts of the project that I do not want to upload to `example.com`.

```
git rm --cached <foldername>
```

I created a remote branch for this repository, pointing at the `example.com` server:

```
git remote add dotcom2 ssh://user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/var/www/example/git/web.git
```

I used `git push dotcom2 fordotcom` to upload the required files to the server. However, the uploaded files do not get copied to the `web` folder. Presumably, this is because they are not in a branch called `master`

```
git push dotcom2 fordotcom
Counting objects: 111, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (105/105), done.
Writing objects: 100% (111/111), 30.69 MiB | 3.91 MiB/s, done.
Total 111 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/var/www/example/git/web.git
 * [new branch]      fordotcom -> fordotcom
```

What would be a good solution for this? I can imagine:

1. Merging the `fordotcom` files to `master` on the remote server (but is this even possible, given that they come from a different repository?)
2. Manually copying files from the second repository to the first repository (but then any updates to the second repository will not be automatically applied to the first)
3. Adding the appropriate folders of the second repository to the first repository so the same files are tracked by both repositories (but is this wise, and how would I do it, given that the repositories have different root folders?)
4. Creating an `git/app.git/` folder alongside the `git/web.git/` folder and using that for the remote for the second repository (but will this cause a clash if the two repositories try to update files in the same location?)
5. Adopting some completely different solution that you can suggest, because you have more experience of using git than I have.

Answer (score 0):

Add an echo in your post-receive hook: it should show you it is triggered when you are pushing your orphan branch from the second repo.

But a `git checkout -f` does check out the default branch: `master`.
This would push a different branch:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    branch=`echo $ref | cut -d/ -f3`
    GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/local/checkout git checkout -f $branch
done
```

Or consider [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bad-mushroom/9844887).

But make sure your second branch has the full set of files needed for your website, or you would override/remove files in the destination folder `/var/www/example/web` through a force `git checkout` ([`git checkout -f`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout--f))

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer. I will provide feedback as soon as I have had the chance to test it.